# Updating table of contents in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro for my word document which is meant to update all the fields and all the table of contents.

```
Sub UpdateFields()
    Dim oStory As Range
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                oStory.Fields.Update
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
    Set oStory = Nothing

    Dim TOC As TableOfContents
    For Each TOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        TOC.Update
    Next
End Sub
```

However, when it is run I get this error.

[image]
<sup>*Error and then debug below*</sup>
I would appreciate any help in fixing the problem.

Comment: Can you step through the code (F8 in the vba editor) to see where the error occurs?

Comment: @RichHolton I just did that. It showed it entered the `For Each TOC`, then when it went to `TOC.Update` it showed the dialog box shown in the image

Comment: Sorry, I got mostly nothing. I see people recommending that Track Changes be off. Do you have it on? If so, try running your code with it off.

Comment: @RichHolton Unfortunately it wasn't on in the first place. Do you get the error on your system?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Word, but, I get an error too. Stepping through the code shows it exits all loops and re-starts the routine entirely at the line TOC.Update first time round, then crashes at it 2nd time round. Looking At ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents I have a count of just 1 (one table of contents) which seems to make the "for each" loop  redundant - or can a document have more than 1 Table of Contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by naming the sub `UpdateFields`. For unknown reasons this name is reserved in Word VBA. Rename the sub to an allowed name (for example, `FieldUpdates`) and the code will work fine.

Comment: This is great thanks. It would make sense if none of it worked because of that but how strange only part of it didn't work because of that

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown indicates that the TableOfContents specified for update doesn't exist. Word will produce errors of this type when using `For ... Each` loops to access some of its collections. The number of TOCs Word is aware of may have changed while editing the document. To avoid the error, avoid `For ... Each` enumerations. Use code like the following instead.

```
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .TablesOfContents.Count
        .TableOfContents(i).Update
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the answer above solved the problem